# Taking multiple samples from the same population

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, variance, sample

I am new to stats and I am having difficulty understanding the variances for multiple samples taken from the same population.

Suppose the population weight of a group of men has mean 80 kg and standard deviation 8.
What is the probability of 2 men weighing more than 190kg? What is the probability of 30 men weighing more than 2440?

I suppose I can calculate the probability involving 30 men using the CLT and derive 18.1% by pnorm(2440/30, 80, 8/sqrt(30), FALSE).

How should the probability of 2 men weighing more than 190kg be calculated since CLT cannot be used?

Comment: CLT is the approximation, however in this case you do not need it, what you used in your formula is a convolution, which can be calculated analytically for the normal distribution for 2, 30, or more distributions.

Comment: You need some kind of assumption about the distribution of weights for the $2$ case